# Can't access model data using Model name in CakePHP 2.x with PHP version 5.3.27

Tags: php, cakephp

On my development server, I installed PHP (5.5), MySQL and Apache. The hosting company only supports up to PHP version 5.3.27. I don't really work in PHP, often so I might be missing something obvious here, but my problems are the following:

```
CakeSession::read('User.stuff')['more_stuff']; // works on 5.5
CakeSession::read('User.stuff')['more_stuff']; // syntax error on 5.3... wat?!
```

I managed to fix the above issue by assigning `CakeSession::read('User.stuff')` to a temp variable, and then accessing more stuff with `$tmp['more_stuff']`.

However, I have a bigger problem. I can't seem to access model names by their model name in arrays returned from databases. Namely, the following code stopped working:

```
$some_model['ModelName']['model_field']; //works on 5.5
$some_model['ModelName']['model_field']; //warning about 'ModelName' being a non-existant index.
```

When I try `$some_model[0]['model_field']` it works just fine.

Cheers!

---

**EDIT**: Ok, turns out < PHP 5.4 doesn't support subscripting return values. Still weird, but it explains the first problem.

Comment: Please also mention your _exact_ CakePHP version!

Comment: @ndm version is 2.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out, [**array dereferencing**](http://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) with function/method call expressions is only supported as of PHP 5.4, nothing special about it, it's simply a feature of newer PHP versions.

Your other problem is most probably not that string indices magically don't work anymore, but simply that the structure of the array you are accessing is different.

Where this difference might stem from? Pretty hard to tell without any context. You should provide some code that can be used to reproduce your situation, and you should also do some more debugging on your own, trace back the function call flow and check at which point the data becomes different.

Comment: So far, I'm suspecting that it might be the MySQL PDO driver. I've contacted the hosting company and they said they'll look into it. Also, the problem is much deeper than "a different" array structure. Not even CakePHP internals relating to models work properly.

Comment: Yeah, it was the pdo_mysql extension. It wasn't loaded properly (although the hosting company insisted it was). I managed to guide them through the steps on how to install it, and then it started working :-)

Comment: Hi! I realise this is an old answer. Although, maybe you could expand it to explain the the second issue described in the question is due to the `mysql_pdo` extension not being loaded, just in case someone stumbles into this—oddly specific—question.